# Python3.9, Tesseract 5, PyQT5 from desktop to Android device. Possible?

Tags: python, android, pyqt5, tesseract

I have made an small non-comercial Py program that performs some simple OCR tasks, it works well enough in both Windows and Linux systems, but the usage doesn't feel right, i figured out that it would be much better running on an Android device.

The problem is i have almost 0 knowledge of Java (i'm just learning) so i would like to "reuse" my Python code.

So to be precise, my question is:

**Is it possible to port my Python 3.9 program that uses [opencv 2, Tesseract 5, PyQT5, pandas, numpy and matplotlib] to an Android device?**

If so, i would really appreciate some pointers in the right direction.

I have done my fair share of googling and found out about Kivy but also about pyqtdeploy, now im not sure if i should just trash the PyQT5 code and replace it with Kivy.

Also the more puzzling matter for me is Tesseract, seems logical that it should work on an Android device, but in the desktop i had to install Tesseract executable and have no idea how to do that on Android, also i have a .traineddata file i really need would it also work on Android?

Well, i think that's more than enough questions for a first timer.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry but we don't really provide suggestions about modules/libraries, nor tutorials or advise about generic porting.